# Restore a Linked Server from backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, linked-server

A linked server has been (accidentally) removed from a SQL Server instance and nobody knows the credentials to re-create it from scratch.

So, is there a way to restore the linked server from a backup (presumably *msdb*) taken before its deletion?

Comment: Can you just change the password on the target system? Or create new credentials to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally used details in master.dbo.sysservers (SQL Server 2000) to recreate the linked server and created new credentials in order to connect.

Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

the system view sys.servers contains the details you need, however, I'm not sure if a restore of master or msdb will give you that.

Comment: No, you can't find the credentials of the linked server in sys.servers